# Let $G$ be a planar graph with $n$ vertices, then $\lambda_1(G) \leq −3 \lambda_n(G)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

> Let $G$ be a planar graph with $n$ vertices. Show that  $\lambda_1(G) \leq −3 \lambda_n(G)$.

Let $\chi(G)$ denote the chromatic number of the graph $G$. Let $\lambda_1(G) , \lambda_n(G)$ denote the largest and smallest eigenvalue of $G$.

Then we have a result in hand: Let $G$ be a graph with $n$ vertices and with at least one edge. Then $$\chi(G) \geq 1-\frac{\lambda_1(G)}{\lambda_n(G)}$$

If $\chi(G) = 4$, then we have $\lambda_1(G) \leq −3 \lambda_n(G)$.

But is it always true that chromatic number of a  planer graph is $4$?

Comment: Trees are planar.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil can you give some hints to do the problem?

Comment: $\chi(G)\leq 4$ for a planar graph $G$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem

Comment: I also used four color theorem to conclude